# Can't compile react native project with Google Services Analytics

Tags: android, react-native, google-analytics, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I've been using react native and added the adjust sdk after following the instructions, have not been able to compile the project on the android side.
The issue I've had is with regards to this line in the build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
```

If that line isn't in there, then it compile's without issue, but with it there, it doesn't work with this error (first couple of lines for context):

```
:app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease

Running dex as a separate process.

To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has 1024 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to at least 1536 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html


AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error converting bytecode to dex:\nCause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/zzf;","sources":[{}],"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:\ncom.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/zzf;\n\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:591)\n\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:546)\n\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:528)\n\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)\n\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)\n","tool":"Dex"}

:app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 36.108 secs
```

The core exception seems to be:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
    Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/zzf;
```

The only reason I use this library is because of these instructions:
https://github.com/adjust/react_native_sdk#google-play-services

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

FYI: I have tried a bunch of solutions such as trying `force=true` on the library to no luck from just random googling

***The rest of my build gradle and package.json for context***

build.grade

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"]
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        //multiDexEnabled true
    }
    //dexOptions {
    //    preDexLibraries = false
    //}
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-adjust')
    compile project(':react-native-version-number')
    compile project(':react-native-fcm')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-dialogs')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-camera')
    compile project(':realm')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1' //this decides your firebase SDK version
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.compile
  into 'libs'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and package.json:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.5.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "rev": "adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 7'",
    "release:android": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd ..",
    "cdapk": "cd android/app/build/outputs/apk",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "chroma-js": "^1.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "moment": "^2.16.0",
    "react": "~15.4.0-rc.4",
    "react-native": "0.38.0",
    "react-native-adjust": "^4.11.3",
    "react-native-animatable": "^0.6.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-dialogs": "0.0.19",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-fcm": "^2.5.5",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.23.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.2.8",
    "react-native-mimetype": "0.0.7",
    "react-native-modal-picker": "0.0.16",
    "react-native-navbar": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.7.5",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.35.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-search-bar": "^2.16.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-tabs": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-version-number": "^0.1.2",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "realm": "^0.14.3",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "redux-saga": "^0.12.1",
    "z-schema": "^3.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "17.0.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.0",
    "eslint": "^3.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.3.0",
    "jest": "17.0.3",
    "jest-react-native": "17.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "~15.4.0-rc.4",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.3.1",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust React Native SDK needs this dependency to be able to read Google Play Services Advertising Identifier. Maybe your project contains some of the plugins which are already including this part of Google Play Services library so adding this dependency on your own might be causing multiple references to it.

You can try skipping adding this dependency and check Adjust SDK verbose logs when tracking session or event in sandbox and in case you see that parameter named `gps_adid` is being sent with session/event package, then that means that your app already contains part of Google Play Services library that Adjust SDK needs in order to read Google Play Services Advertising Identifier and in that case there is no need for you to add:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
```